# Different Tor bundle settings for different browsers

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I want to compartmentalize my digital activity dividing business, social, and general browsing.

I don't want to use VPN because even if I pay, there is still an option for my data to be used the way I don't want. So instead of trusting a VPN it's better to use different tor exit nodes at least to split and distribute the whole picture, right?

So how can I use different tor settings for each compartment? Basically I just need 3 different sets of exit nodes for each compartment and 3 browsers (I consider using different Firefox profiles with extensions for business and social domains and stock tor browser for surfing). As you can deduce I will login to accounts in the first 2 domains.

I can't run Qubes OS on my hardware, it's just doesn't work, I've tried. I am an average Linux user.

Comment: just duplicate tor browser folders and configure browsers